# Bcrypt.compare() returning only false, Used Under Promises

Tags: node.js, express, bcrypt

I am using Bcrypt for hashing passwords and storing it in the database,

Bcrypt is returning false, when I retrieve the hashed password from the database, and compare with the typed user password.

I am using it under Promise, but bcrypt is returning false on the correct password

Here is the code:

```
userSchema.statics.findByCredentials = function(email, password) {
const User = this;

return User.findOne({email}).then((user) => {
    if(!user) {
        return Promise.reject();
    }
    // console.log(user.password);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err,res) => {
             if(res) {
                 resolve(user);
             }
             else {
                 reject("Problem here");
             }
            console.log(res);

        });            
    });
});
```

};

I am trying promise chain to the main file i.e server.js and return the details to the user, but it's not working.

Here is the route code of express:

```
app.post('/users/login', (req, res) => {
const body = _.pick(req.body, ['email', 'password']);
// res.send(body);

User.findByCredentials(body.email, body.password)
    .then((user) => {
        res.send(user);
    }).catch((e) => res.send(e));
```

});

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [promise api](https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js#with-promises) for `bcrypt`?

It might look like this:

```
userSchema.statics.findByCredentials = function(email, password) {
  const User = this;

  return User.findOne({email}).then((user) => {
      if(!user) {
          return Promise.reject();
      }
      // console.log(user.password);

      return bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
        .then(res => {
          if (res) {
            return user;
          }
          throw new Error('Problem here');
        });
  });
}
```

If not, you might be getting an error, so you could check the `err` argument to see if something came back from there. Other than that, as long as `user.password` is the hashed version of the original password, then it should be working.

Comment: Nothing is coming back its just the empty object. I tried the with promise as well. It wont work!
Its still showing false after comparing
Here is the code to save hashed password:

userSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    
    const user = this;
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err,salt) => {
        bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, (err, res) => {
            user.password = res;      
            next();     
        });
    });
});


I couldnt find my way through, what else could be done?

Comment: What's an empty object? Does your schema remove `password`? I've seen other implementation where `password` is removed from `user` and something like `passwordHash` is used instead.

Comment: Its just removing token, not the password, its fetching hashedPassword from the Database

Comment: Sorry, from the information shown here, it seems like that should be working. Maybe you found a bug in `bcrypt`? You might be able to open an issue there with more details... like results of doing `console.log(password, user.password)` before calling `bcrypt.compare`.